# how can I draw it using starUml

Tags: uml, staruml

I am using staruml, I find it is hard to draw a perfect UML class diagram when the relation is complex.[uml diagram](http://img360.imageshack.us/my.php?image=serviceloadertw5.jpg)

Comment: Can you give us some more detail about what it is you are trying to draw please.

Answer (score 3):

If your UML Diagrams are getting too complex try breaking the digram up into several diagrams each of which covers a smaller subset of classes. You may even want to move your classes into seperate packages to keep them organised. In Star UML (and other UML Tools) classes can appear in more than one diagram so you can include all the classes from one package plus the classes from a differnt package's public interface.

Comment: thanks for your help. do you have sample star uml file which I could learn from that.